Gnome - Grouping does not show up in application-menu
On Gnome, I want to use the application-menu located on top left of the screen:

Now I want the applications within this menu to be grouped. On the screenshot below you can see a grouping displayed by the gnome-application alacarte, where you can see the grouping within Multimedia:

Though this grouping does not show up in my application menu. How can I fix this?
GNOME Shell 44.9

Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux trixie/sid     
          Kernel: Linux 6.6.15-amd64
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: TOSHIBA
  Hardware Model: PORTEGE R30-A
Firmware Version: Version 4.20
   Firmware Date: Thu 2014-04-17
    Firmware Age: 9y 11month 2w 2d

